# How to automatically update relative CSS paths for minification?

Tags: css, node.js, gulp, minify, postcss

I would like to update all relative paths for minification, because I use separate folders for each `JS`/`CSS` component and folder depth can also be different for each component, for example:

```
css/
    style.min.css // final minified and processed file
    common.scss
    components/
        gallery/
            gallery.scss // url(../../../img/mypic.png)
img/
    mypic.png
```

After minification, my style in `style.min.css` will still have `../../../img/mypic.png`. However, it must be updated to `../img/mypic.png`, otherwise webbrowsers will not find the picture.

How can I automatically do this with `PostCSS` or another package?

I found `postcss-url` project and it provides a function for a custom URL transformation, but I didn't find any example how to do this.

Right now I use `gulp`, `nodejs`, `autoprefixer` and `postcss` for my minification.

Comment: If you want us to help you with your build it would be helpful to actually provide the code for your build. Read [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a parameter called `url` in `postcss-url` that can be used to pass a custom function to `postcss-url`. This function will be able to modify URLs for `postcss-url`, but the code must be manually written. Here is what I use in my project:

```
var outDir = './src/css'; // output folder for CSS
gulp.task('min:css', function () {
    return gulp
        .src(cssInput)
        .pipe(postcss([
            autoprefixer(),
            postcssurl({
                // this function will modify URLs
                url: function (asset) {
                    if (!asset.url || asset.url.indexOf("base64") !== -1) {
                        return asset.url;
                    }
                    return path.relative(outDir, asset.absolutePath).split("\\").join("/");
                }
            })
        ]))
        ...
});
```